# ISIS Suicide Blasts Kill More Than 220 Dead In Southern Syria

Tags: sentence, syntactic-analysis, headline-english

Going through [this](https://www.ndtv.com/world-news/isis-suicide-blasts-kill-more-than-220-dead-in-sweida-southern-syria-1889818) news article on NDTV website, I saw the headline **'ISIS Suicide Blasts Kill More Than 220 Dead In Southern Syria'**. Is this usage correct? Or should it be 'ISIS Suicide Blasts Kill More Than 220 In Southern Syria'?

[image: see the snapshot]

Comment: As written, the people killed were already dead, so yes, it is poorly written.

Comment: Maybe they just had "More than 200 dead in southern Syria" at first and then forgot to remove the word after adding the rest of the words.

Comment: You are correct. "Killing someone dead" is wrong.

Comment: Wrong, unless you consider them as two statements. ISIS Suicide Blasts Kill (stop) More Than 220 Dead. News media headlines are often written weird. But probably this is just a mistake.

Comment: Yeah, probably just a mistake.

Comment: There is a long history in the U.S. of using "kills ... dead" for emphasis. In fact, for decades, "Kills Bugs Dead" was the tag-line for Raid bug spray, as [this advertisement posted on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7G1YPX6Sjx0) illustrates. The ad is worth seeing if only to observe how the manufacturer recommends deploying the poison on or near fruits and vegetables.

Comment: It's hard to tell from the excerpt posted, but maybe ISIS was trying to stop a zombie uprising and the website didn't want to offend its life-challenged readers?

Comment: @SvenYargs If you think that ad is bad...a number of years ago when I was working at a boarding school I went down to the kitchen in the middle of the night and found a student spraying the leftovers with Raid be because he saw some cockroaches on the counter. His retort to my comments was "Well, it's never hurt me before."

Comment: @Cascabel: Yes, some people have a very clear idea that bug spray can't hurt them because they're not bugs. I still remember the extreme jealousy I felt as a young child in Corpus Christi, Texas, watching other children cavort in the plume of a slow-moving fogger truck as it emitted clouds of insecticide—and not being allowed to join them because (my mother insisted) "it's poison."

Comment: @SvenYargs Ah...the good old days of _Dichlorodiphenyltrichloroethane_. I actually think they are still using that crap here, but maybe it is preferable to Zika, malaria, and Dengue (which I would not wish on anyone-really hurts).